# Regular expression for randomly appear new lines (PHP)

Tags: regex

Problem to find the right regular expression for tricky RDF/XML data. I try to find and extract only literals in the data, which vaguely means extracting data values between two tags.

I tried an expression `>.*</` for the data below, but it only returns 4 literals, and misses 2 literals. Basically, Chinese values (appeared two times) in the data are not extracted (i.e. `<rdfs:comment>` and `<dbo:abstract>`), probably due to new lines. It is hard to predict how and where the new lines and characters may appear as the value (i.e. it could be before, between, and after any characters, and repeated several times, or no repeat). So, it is best to extract all possible cases. Do you have a good idea?

```
<rdfs:label xml:lang="en">1969</rdfs:label>
<rdfs:label xml:lang="pt">1969</rdfs:label>
<rdfs:comment xml:lang="zh">请参看： 
*  1969年电影 
*  1969年文学 
*  1969年音乐 
*  1969年体育 
*  1969年电视</rdfs:comment>
<dbo:abstract xml:lang="zh">请参看： 
*  1969年电影 
*  1969年文学 
*  1969年音乐 
*  1969年体育 
*  1969年电视</dbo:abstract>
<dbo:abstract xml:lang="nl">Het jaar 1969 is een jaartal volgens de christelijke jaartelling.</dbo:abstract>
<dbo:abstract xml:lang="it">Il 1969 (MCMLXIX in numeri romani) è un anno del XX secolo.</dbo:abstract>
```

I think the solution would be along the line of dotall (\s), but not sure how it works properly in this case. Thanks!

Comment: `Problem to find the right regular expression for ... XML data` actually the problem is that you are trying to use regex to parse XML in the first place.  Please research how to use a proper XML parser and make your life much easier!

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but that is not exactly what I am looking for. The question here is what I can do only using regular expression. Making my life easier or not is another issue/story. If regular expression is well designed, then there should be a solution somehow, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My colleague came up with a solution `<[^/:]+:[^>]+[^/]>[^<]*</`, which works (at least as long as I checked with some data). Thanks for your contribution anyway!

Answer (score 2):

That's right, you can use the `s` mode, yet you might have to strengthen your left and right boundaries, with some expression looking like:

```
$re = '/<([^>]*?)>(.*?)<(\s*\/[^>]*?)>/s';
$str = '<rdfs:label xml:lang="en">1969</rdfs:label>
<rdfs:label xml:lang="pt">1969</rdfs:label>
<rdfs:comment xml:lang="zh">请参看：
*  1969年电影
*  1969年文学
*  1969年音乐
*  1969年体育
*  1969年电视</rdfs:comment>
<dbo:abstract xml:lang="zh">请参看：
*  1969年电影
*  1969年文学
*  1969年音乐
*  1969年体育
*  1969年电视</dbo:abstract>
<dbo:abstract xml:lang="nl">Het jaar 1969 is een jaartal volgens de christelijke jaartelling.</dbo:abstract>
<dbo:abstract xml:lang="it">Il 1969 (MCMLXIX in numeri romani) è un anno del XX secolo.</dbo:abstract>';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

var_dump($matches);
```

#### Output

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(43) "<rdfs:label xml:lang="en">1969</rdfs:label>"
    [1]=>
    string(24) "rdfs:label xml:lang="en""
    [2]=>
    string(4) "1969"
    [3]=>
    string(11) "/rdfs:label"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(43) "<rdfs:label xml:lang="pt">1969</rdfs:label>"
    [1]=>
    string(24) "rdfs:label xml:lang="pt""
    [2]=>
    string(4) "1969"
    [3]=>
    string(11) "/rdfs:label"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(140) "<rdfs:comment xml:lang="zh">请参看：
*  1969年电影
*  1969年文学
*  1969年音乐
*  1969年体育
*  1969年电视</rdfs:comment>"
    [1]=>
    string(26) "rdfs:comment xml:lang="zh""
    [2]=>
    string(97) "请参看：
*  1969年电影
*  1969年文学
*  1969年音乐
*  1969年体育
*  1969年电视"
    [3]=>
    string(13) "/rdfs:comment"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(140) "<dbo:abstract xml:lang="zh">请参看：
*  1969年电影
*  1969年文学
*  1969年音乐
*  1969年体育
*  1969年电视</dbo:abstract>"
    [1]=>
    string(26) "dbo:abstract xml:lang="zh""
    [2]=>
    string(97) "请参看：
*  1969年电影
*  1969年文学
*  1969年音乐
*  1969年体育
*  1969年电视"
    [3]=>
    string(13) "/dbo:abstract"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(108) "<dbo:abstract xml:lang="nl">Het jaar 1969 is een jaartal volgens de christelijke jaartelling.</dbo:abstract>"
    [1]=>
    string(26) "dbo:abstract xml:lang="nl""
    [2]=>
    string(65) "Het jaar 1969 is een jaartal volgens de christelijke jaartelling."
    [3]=>
    string(13) "/dbo:abstract"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(103) "<dbo:abstract xml:lang="it">Il 1969 (MCMLXIX in numeri romani) è un anno del XX secolo.</dbo:abstract>"
    [1]=>
    string(26) "dbo:abstract xml:lang="it""
    [2]=>
    string(60) "Il 1969 (MCMLXIX in numeri romani) è un anno del XX secolo."
    [3]=>
    string(13) "/dbo:abstract"
  }
}
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/J8phpS/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/J8phpS/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

Comment: I think your pattern can be simplified to `<[^>]*>([^<>]*)</[^>]*>` See https://regex101.com/r/j2XcOb/1 In this part `<([^>]*?)>` there is no need to make the quantifier lazy as it can not cross the `>` due to the negated character class.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot to include something really important in the data.

Comment: Thank you guys. it is very close. But, it does not work, because I am very sorry that I forgot to include something really important in the data. There are also tags which have no literals, which need to be taken into account. e.g.    `<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://dbpedia.org/resource/List_of_events_broadcast_on_Wide_World_of_Sports_(U.S._TV_series)">
    <rdfs:seeAlso rdf:resource="http://dbpedia.org/resource/1969" />
  </rdf:Description>`